# when this statement is true?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

let $T$ be an operator and $T^2=T^{*2}$. Whit which condition i can conclude that $T=T^*$?
i know that if $T$ is positive and $T^2=T^{*2}$, then we can conclude that $T=T^*$. Is there any condition except positivity for this conclusion?

Comment: What is your definition for positive operators? Most sensible definitions include that $T$ is self-adjoint, so your conclusion would be kind of trivial.

Answer (score 1):

You can write any operator as $T = A + i B$ where $A$ and $B$ are self adjoint. The condition for $T^2$ to be self adjoint is that $A B + B A = 0$ (while the condition for $T$ to be self adjoint is that $B = 0$).  To construct a counterexample, find two self adjoint operators $A, B$ with $B \ne 0$, such that the pair that *anti-commutes*,  $A B + B A = 0$.  You can do this with 2-by-2 matrices.

**Edit**:   Complex numbers are in particular operators on one dimensional Hilbert space!  Can you find a one-dimensional example?